# Cannot toggle personalization scope programmatically

Tags: development, web-part, personalization

I'm trying to switch personalisation scope for the current user:

```
    protected void lnkToggleMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var wpmgr = (SPWebPartManager)SPWebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page);
            wpmgr.Personalization.ToggleScope();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

However, the `ToggleScope` method throws this exception:

> 'wpmgr.Personalization.ToggleScope()' threw an exception of type
>   'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'
>       base {System.SystemException}: {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call
>   stack.}
>       ExceptionState: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Any thought?

FYI, the `wpmgr.Personalization.CanEnterSharedScope` property is returning `true`

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I can't tell why you're not using an SPLimitedWebPartManager but the standard .net webpartmanager:

If you can get hold of either the SPWeb / SPFile object you're working on you could try calling mySPFileObject.GetLimitedWebPartManager which takes a personalizationScope enum as a parameter.

[MSDN: SPFile:GetLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.getlimitedwebpartmanager.aspx)

Comment: I want to switch the context of the whole page. What you are mentioning only allows to manipulate the page's webpart.